# bash script for comparing

Tags: bash, awk, amazon-s3

I am trying to write a bash script.

I am on Amazon-s3. I have a bucket1, which contains bucket2, bucket3, bucket4. The bucket 2 has b1, b2, b3, b4, b5 - in which each of them contain tar files being created with    nd the file name.

When I do a s3cmd `--recursive ls s3://bucket1/bucket2/ | awk '{print$1}'` I print the date of all the tar files which are generated.

I want the date on the computer to compare it with that list and print the last 1 week of the files which have been created.

Format of date on s3 : year/month/date

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use gnu [date](/questions/tagged/date) with the `+%s` option to get seconds, and then easily compare dates in whatever format, i.e.

```
> (( ( $(date +%s) - $(date -d "2014/03/08" +%s) ) < (7*24*60*60) )) \
&& echo "Less than week ago" \
|| echo "More than week ago"
More than week ago

> (( ( $(date +%s) - $(date -d "2014/04/03" +%s) ) < (7*24*60*60) )) \
&& echo "Less than week ago" \
|| echo "More than week ago"
Less than week ago
```